# SQL Database Backup with minimum storage size

Tags: sql-server, backup

I want to take a full backup of a SQL Server DB, but the concern is the other PC where I want to restore is not having enough disk space. I tried zipping the bak file to reduce the size but, even that doesn't help. Is there a way to take a FULL backup in SQL with minimum storage usage? I know, we can take differential backup but that's not an option as I am restoring the database to the new PC for the very first time. I want to know any configurable setting while taking the backup which might help me in reducing the size of the backup file. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Are you using the `COMPRESSION` option? If so, something like a zip archive isn't going to get it any smaller. If the host isn't able to have the (compressed) backup on it due to storage issues though, how is it going to be able to restore the much larger `.mdf` file?

Comment: off-topic - belongs on [dba](https://dba.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: @Larnu: Thanks for your help. I didn't use COMPRESSION option, after reading your comment, I tried that and it worked. Yeah, that's true, I will have to figure our that part. But, the 1st part of the question is solved. I am able to take the compressed backup. Thank You.